# Not able to pass and Append @variable on the selected query

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_RmsExecuteValidationRule]        
    @nRuleId INT     
AS 
BEGIN        
    -- Local variables        
    DECLARE @sqlstat AS NVARCHAR(MAX)        
    DECLARE @params  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)        
    DECLARE @RULE_QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)     
    DECLARE @FIPS  varchar(5) 

    SET @sqlstat = N'SELECT @RULE_QUERY=RULE_QUERY from GdmValidationRuleMaster where RULE_ID = @nRuleId'        
    --SET @sqlstat =  N'SELECT ' + @RULE_QUERY + '=RULE_QUERY from GdmValidationRuleMaster where RULE_ID = ' + @nRuleId 

    SET @params = N'@nRuleId INT,   @RULE_QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT'        

    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstat, @params, @nRuleId = @nRuleId, @RULE_QUERY= @RULE_QUERY OUTPUT 

    -- Output   
    SELECT @RULE_QUERY            
END
```

When we `Exec usp_RmsExecuteValidationRule 1`, it returns `@RULE_QUERY` i.e:

```
SELECT GDMID AS GDM_ID from @FIPSName+CADMIN1 WHERE INTPRIORITY IS NULL
```

Here I have intentionally added @FIPSName+ As prefix because I have another table `LCountry` with a `FIPS` column:

```
FIPS
----
GM
FR
UK
AN
BE
BU
BL
BR
BH
CA
AU
VT
CI
CH
CO
CS
EZ
AS
DA
EC
SP
AR
BD
BB
BF
AV
AA
AC
DO
CU
CJ
DR
GP
GJ
HA
JM
ST
RQ
SC
MB
MH
XN
XM
XJ
VC
VI
TK
TD
TB
RN
XL
XK
VQ
GR
GT
GQ
HK
HO
HU
ID
EI
IS
GZ
XC
WE
IN
IT
SM
JA
LS
LU
MX
NU
NL
NO
NZ
PM
PE
RP
PL
PO
RO
SW
SI
LO
ES
TU
TW
SZ
VE
SN
SB
PF
PG
PC
NE
NF
MQ
US
SX
TE
TT
WQ
BQ
DQ
BS
CK
CQ
CR
AY
AT
BV
LQ
KQ
JQ
JU
KT
IO
IP
```

Using loop I am able fetch data  using ObjectID of Lcountry.

```
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT , @MaxBcountryObjId INT, 
        @FIPSName NVARCHAR(100)
SELECT @LoopCounter = min(OBJECTID) , @MaxBcountryObjId = max(OBJECTID) 
FROM dbo.LCOUNTRY

WHILE(@LoopCounter IS NOT NULL
      AND @LoopCounter <= @MaxBcountryObjId)
BEGIN
   SELECT @FIPSName = FIPS
   FROM dbo.LCOUNTRY WHERE OBJECTID = @LoopCounter

   PRINT @FIPSName  
   SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1
```

This query Return @FIPSName.

**QUESTION**

I want to This return Value @FIPName Should Appends on Rule_Query return Value.
and the same value can be executed too.

For Example :

```
SELECT GDMID AS GDM_ID from @FIPSName+CADMIN1 WHERE INTPRIORITY IS NULL
Changes Into

SELECT GDMID AS GDM_ID from GM+CADMIN1 WHERE INTPRIORITY IS NULL
Changes Into 

GDMID
------         (The above query must be executed and Return GDMID.)
1198
```

Comment: @Gordon  kindly suggest solution ..Thanks.

Comment: @vkp kindly suggest solution ..Thanks

Comment: @rory.ap kindly suggest solution ..Thanks

Comment: just a heads up, they aren't getting alters when you use`@Gordon` or `@vkp` because they haven't commented on your thread.

Comment: @scsimon kindly suggest solution ..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want to execute

```
SELECT @RULE_QUERY=RULE_QUERY from GdmValidationRuleMaster where RULE_ID = @nRuleId
```

Above query will give you the result.

I think you don't need to use sp_executesql.